# Hide day in JQuery datepicker in a specific date input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have two input fields for which I'm using datepicker:

1. On the first I want to hide the day selector and the 'Today' button.
2. On the second I want a normal datepicker

To achieve the desired effect on the 1st, I'm using a hack, like:

```
 $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));

        }
    });
```

With CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
<label for="startDate">Outra Data :</label>
<input name="outraData" id="outraData" />
```

I tried:

```
#startDate .ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

And:

```
.date-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/qVd86/2/)

Comment: On the first I want to hide the day selector and the 'Today' button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply apply the css [By inspecting using dev tools(F12)]

```
.ui-datepicker-current{
    display: none ;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/qVd86/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but on the 1st date picker I still have the day selector

Comment: day selector??  can you elobrate it?

Comment: In the normal datepicker, you may select the day in the calendar. I want to select only the month, so the date will be the first of the selected month.~

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following option in your datepicker to hide the buttons:

```
showButtonPanel: true
```

Since you want 2 different datepickers, use the following:

HTML

```
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" />
<label for="startDate">Outra Data :</label>
<input name="outraData" id="outraData" />
```

JS

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,        
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });


    $('#outraData').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
```

Notice that i have called the datepickers on the basis of IDs.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xQc8x/)**